# Anti-spamming in Google Forms using some form of Captcha

Tags: forms, google-forms, spam-prevention

I have a Google Form that works in conjuction with a facebook Page of mine, that has become quite popular. Recently, I have become the victim of spamming on the form, to the point that I have to constantly hop on different forms as the flooded ones get unusable.

As Google Forms does not implement `reCaptcha` elements, does any of you know of any effective ways to avoid spamming on your forms from a bot/program? My form gathers 300 responses daily (normal traffic, spamming takes this to ~10,000 a day, making the form unusable), and I would like to avoid forcing users to log-in using google and limiting their responses to 1 per user.

### Things I have tried:

- Shuffling question order (there's 4 of them, the spammer/attacker
  program can just parse question titles, and see where to submit what)
- Placing a second section on the form, even if it just contains a "submit response" button and nothing else
- Place a captcha-like question with data validation (Usually a "what's 10+2" or similar, but as I have to change it manually, it's a chore to do it every day) and the spammer can easily set his program to input the new answer and spam thousands of responses in a single hour.
- Forcing users to log-in and limiting them to 1 response per, by using the "Limit responses to 1 per person" setting, but that goes against the goal of the form, which should store as many responses from one user as he sees fit (probably 2 or 3 per user, per week).
- Reporting a problem with my form to Google. Heh.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the Form embedded in Facebook?  Can you use any client side JavaScript code in whatever the Form is embedded in?  If you could somehow make a call to an Apps Script file from Facebook before loading the Form, that might be the only path to finding a solution.  In any case, I think that any possible solution would need to go through some type of Facebook capability.  I don't think you can solve this directly in Google Forms.  (Unless you make the user sign in to their Google account)